# Updating sql table in R using library(odbc) returns error: external pointer is not valid

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc

I am trying to perform:

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQL Server",
                 Server = "myServer",
                 Database = "myDataBase",
                 UID = "myUser",
                 PWD = "myPassword")

dbSendQuery(conn = con, 
            "INSERT INTO etl.VALOR_ETL (INTCODIGO,SERCODIGOEXTERNO,VALDATA,VALVALOR) 
             VALUES ('Generica', 'TESTE', '2018-01-01','2')" )
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in new_result(connection@ptr, statement) : 
external pointer is not valid
```

I have tried other packages, however, I could not find any other one that allowed to query "insert into".

What would be this issue related to?

Comment: Period qualifying names such as `etl.` in SQL Server denotes different schemas apart from the default `dbo`. The latest development version of [odbc](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/91) as discussed here indicates it support such queries. Try updating your `DBI` package or use development version: `devtools::install_github("r-dbi/DBI")`.

Comment: This was a bug in the `odbc` package which did not support MS SQL schema names syntax. See also: https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/265